# Recursive function with Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm using an api that returns comment objects, the comments can have kids that are also comment objects.

I'm trying to retrieve the entire comment thread with recursion but its not working, as soon as a comment doesn't have a kid the function ends early and the result returned doesn't contain the entire comment thread.

How can I change the function so the resolve occurs after all comments have been checked to have no kids.

example of a comment object thats returned by the api

```
{
  "id": 16020433,
  "kids": [
    16021684,
    16021721,
    16021659
  ],
  "title": "Why isn't literally every train automated?",
  "type": "story"
}
```

Here is my code:

```
function getCommentsWrapper(id) {
  let comments = [];
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    function recurseComments(id) {
      let url = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`;
      let comment = {};
      fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(cmt => {
          comment = cmt
          comments.push(comment);
          if (comment.kids) {
            comment.kids.forEach(id => recurseComments(id));
          } else {
            resolve(comments)
          }
        })
    }

    recurseComments(id);
  })



  // call the function with
  getCommentsWrapper("16033496")
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the call count technique, as in the code below. Or you can use a library such as [Bluebrid](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html). I think they have a lot of options.

I think also Promise.all can do the required, but in my past experience, adding new promises to Promise.all while the promise array is being handled was not reliable.

```
function getCommentsWrapper(id) {

  var promises = [];
  let count = 0;

  let futureValue = new Promise((resolveAll, rejectAll)=>{
      let comments = [];
      let call = (id) => {
        count++;
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          let url = `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${id}.json`;
          let comment = {};
          fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(cmt => {
              comment = cmt
              comments.push(comment);
              if (comment.kids) {
                comment.kids.forEach(id => call(id));
              }

              resolve();
              count--;
              if(count < 1){
                resolveAll(comments);
              }
            })
        });
      };

      call(id);
  });
  return futureValue;
}


// call the function with
getCommentsWrapper("16033496")
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Thanks adding the count variable to track the number of times the comments nested works great. What is the reason for creating the extra Promise to wrap around the Promise doing the fetch?

Comment: So, you can follow the then pattern you have in your code, as in getCommentsWrapper. Otherwise, you will need to create a callback.